# Show and dismis UIAlertController in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, uialertcontroller

I declared a global variable for UIAlertViewController for me to be able to show and dismiss it in different method inside my class. 
I displayed two kinds of alert: First, alert with button which will be displayed when an error is encountered or to display an information message. Second is an alert without button which will be displayed like a progress message.

Here is the sample code:

```
private var alert: UIAlertController? // global declaration

private func showProgressMessage(sender viewController: UIViewController, message alertMessage: String)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.alert= UIAlertController(title: "", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        viewController.present(self.alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

private func showAlertMessage(sender viewController: UIViewController, title alertTitle: String, message alertMessage: String)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        self.alert= UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

        self.alert!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        viewController.present(self.alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

private func method1()
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async
    {
        // some code here
        self.showProgressMessage(sender: self, message:  "Processing...")
        // some code here
    }
}

private func method2()
{
    // some code here
    self.alert!.dismiss(animated: false)
    {
        self.showAlertMessage(sender: self, message:  "Done")
    }

    self.displayOtherViewController()
}

private func displayOtherViewController()
{
    self.alert?.dismiss(animated: false)
    {
        if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Sample")
        {
            let view = viewController as! SampleViewController

            view .modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

            self.present(view , animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In method2, displaying the alert again will take a few seconds to display, same with the view controller.
What is the proper way to show and dismis the UIAlertController in Swift 4?

Comment: few seconds for the animation? Just set the animated property to `false`. We'd be able to understand better if you added a gif to show what is happening and what you want.

Comment: Sorry, it should be milliseconds. sometimes, alert is not displaying at all. I already chaged the animation to false but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your code is initiated from a background thread.
**Even dismiss must be called on main thread**
Try this:

```
private func method2() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.alert!.dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.showAlertMessage(sender: self, message:  "Done")
        }
        self.displayOtherViewController()
    }
}
```